# Why am I receiving 'NaN' from my reducer function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am adding up the quantity in my cart. I pull the state off my redux state using hooks useSelector for all the items in my cart and use reduce to add up all the quantities and display them in my cart icon.

```
const cartItems = useSelector( (state) => state.cart.cartItems)
const itemCount = cartItems.reduce((accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => 
  accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity, 0

)

console.log(itemCount)
```

Item count here is 'NaN'

[My redux cart state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxNlr.png)

Comment: what is carditems we need some example

Comment: Please see linked screenshot of my redux cart state @rcvaram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be for some cartItem the quantity is not a number. You can check if isNaN() and then add the cartItem.quantity to the accumulator. Like this,

```
const cartItems = useSelector( (state) => state.cart.cartItems)
const itemCount = cartItems.reduce((accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => 
{
   if(isNaN(cartItem.quantity)) {
        return accumulatedQuantity;
   }
   return accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity;
}, 0

)

console.log(itemCount)
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I did have some cart items where quantity was not a number and this solved my issue! Thanks! I should do more validation.

Comment: Don't forget to check this answer as correct if this solves your problem.